computing fixed points of a toric action
Let $W_1=\{ ([a : b], [x : y : z]) \in \Bbb{CP^1} \times \Bbb{CP^2}: ay=bx \}$
Given the action of $\Bbb T^2$ on $W_1$ defined as
$(u, v) \cdot ([a : b], [x : y : z]) = ([ua : b], [ux : y : vz])$
How do I compute the fixed points of the action? I am having trouble with the projective coordinates.
I would procede like this: I have to solve the equation:
$(u, v) \cdot ([a : b], [x : y : z]) = ([a : b], [x : y : z])$
$([ua : b], [ux : y : vz]) = ([a : b], [x : y : z])$ and I guess this should hold for every u and v?
Since projective coordinates make sense if  the first coordinate is not 0 we have that $a\neq 0 $and $x \neq 0$  I can normalize:
$([1 : b/(ua)], [1 : y/(ux) : vz/(ux)]) = ([1 : b/a], [1 : y/x : z/x])$
now I can equate the components:
for all u and v I must have
$b/(ua)=b/a \implies b=0$
$y/(ux)=y/x \implies y=0$
$vz/(ux)=z/x \implies z=0$
so the only point I get is  $([1 : b/a], [1 : y/x : z/x])=([1 :0], [1 : 0 : 0])$
But the answer should be:
$v_1 = ([0 : 1], [0 : 1 : 0]), v_2 = ([1 : 0], [1 : 0 : 0]),v3 = ([0 : 1], [0 : 0 : 1]) , v_4 =  ([1 : 0], [0 : 0 : 1])$
What am I doing wrong? How do I obtain the other points?

The action is defined by
$$(u,v)\cdot([a:b],[x:y:z])=([ua:b], [ux:y:vz])$$
Then the set of fixed points is, by definition
$$\{([a:b], [x:y:z])\in\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^2\mid (u,v)\cdot([a:b],[x:y:z])=([a:b],[x:y:z])\forall(u,v)\in\mathbb{T}^2\}$$
This leads to some equations to be solved. Namely,
$$([ua:b], [ux:y:vz]) = ([a:b], [x:y:z])\forall (u,v)\in\mathbb{T}^2$$
Now, firstly, $[ua:b]=[a:b]\iff \exists\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^\times\mid\lambda\cdot(a, b)=(ua, b)$. We distinguish two cases: $b=0$ and $b\neq 0$. If $b=0$ this condition trivially holds since $u\neq 0$. If $b\neq 0$, then it must be true that $\lambda = 1$, so we get the equation $(a, b)=(ua, b)$, which can be true for all $(u, v)\in\mathbb{T}^2$ if and only if $a=0$.
This reduces our search to points of the form $([1:0],[x:y:z])$ or $([0:1], [x:y:z])$. The remainder (i.e. identifying the options for $[x:y:z]$) is done in the same fashion, but will be a bit more tedious. I guess I will leave that part up to you.

The case $b=0 $ is unclear. We have that $\lambda(a,b)=(ua,b)\iff  \lambda a=ua \forall u$ and $\lambda b=b$. Only  $\lambda b=b$ is satisfied trivially. But what about  $\lambda a=ua$ ? I get that $(\lambda-u)a=0 \forall u \iff a=0$, so I get $(0,0)$ and not$ (1:0)$ as expected, but this value should not be allowed, so what is going on?

Shoudn't I take into consideration that $(u,v)∈\Bbb T^2$
only? (u,v) must satisfy the equation of the 2-torus, but what would this equation be? I am looking at here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry

You can choose $\lambda \in\mathbb{C}^\times$. So you choose it to be $u\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}^\times$. Recall that $\mathbb{T}^2 = S^1\times S^1$, and $S^1$ is the set of complex numbers of unit norm. That's how the group action is defined: by complex multiplication.

I am sorry, is your comment answering the first or the second comment? I still don't see what is wrong in my first comment, it clearly shows a contradiction is reached and I can't get something proportional to (1,0), but just (0,0). What exactly is it wrong? And do you find the solution b=0 (but $a \neq 0$) which corresponds to [1:0]?

The point $[0:0]$ does not exist, so that is certainly not a solution. What you should instead deduce from your equation $(\lambda-u)a=0$ is that you can set $\lambda=u$. The $\lambda$ does not need to be the same for all $u$. But all of this should be quite evident if you're familiar with projective coordinates, so maybe it'd be wise to review that first.
